# Je (te) crois que les sorcières existent

Tags: pronoms, verbes, formulation

> Je crois que les sorcières existent.
>
> Je **te** crois que les sorcières existent.

Je ne suis pas sûre que la deuxième phrase soit correcte, je ne trouve pas beaucoup d'exemples contenant *te crois que* sur Internet. Elle devrait l'être, pourtant.

D'après vous, est-ce que la deuxième phrase est correcte ou il faudrait la reformuler ?

Comment: Lambie, stp, cesse d'ajouter "français parlé" à ma question. Je suis d'accord avec Earendelle et Tsudoku.

Comment: I don't think Tsudoku said anything about this. A question was asked by him or her on Meta which I answered and he/she never came back in response. It is spoken French.

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/50202/5

Comment: @Lambie See Earendelle's link above.

Comment: This question is now temporarily locked due to edit wars.

Answer (score 3):

*Je te/vous crois* est simplement une « approbation qui renchérit », de registre familier (LBU14 §1108 b) : « Il ne fait pas chaud. -JE VOUS CROIS, il fait moins dix ! » ([Ac.](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9C5041)). Un *que* peut servir à créer une proposition dont l'importance dépasse la valeur d'une première sous-phrase et ce phénomène se produit aussi dans la langue parlée familière après certaines formulations, dont celle qui nous occupe (LBU14 §1121 a): "« Regarde donc la comtesse de Mascaret comme elle est toujours belle. » / [...]
Quand il l'eut regardée quelque temps, Bernard Grandin répondit avec un accent badin de conviction sincère : / « JE TE CROIS Qu'elle est belle ! »" (Maupassant).

Dans la première phrase, on ne fait que donner son opinion sur l'existence des sorcières.

> [image]]
> <sup>4e para. à 1108 b), *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, 14e, éd. Duculot</sup>[image]
> <sup>4e para. à 1121 a), *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, 14e, éd. Duculot</sup>

Answer (score 0):

La seconde phrase n'est pas du tout de la langue standard ; cependant, on la trouve dans la bouche de personnes de moindre instruction, en particulier dans les campagnes dans un passé récent ; il est possible que de nos jours cette construction soit utilisée moins fréquemment. Il ne faut pas penser qu'elle signifie  ce que la première veut dire. C'est une phrase qui est utilisée pour affirmer avec emphase qu'un certain état de chose est réel lorsque dans une conversation quelqu'un doute de son existence ou emet des opinions quant à sa possible existence. Donc, il n'est pas question non plus de dire à quelqu'un qu'on les croit au moyen de ce type de phrase. Bien sûr, je ne fais référence qu'au français de France.

---

*Addition pour répondre aux commentaires et donner des détails*

C'est une tournure qui est devenue très rare. On en trouve quatre exemples dans les livres Google, un seul qui soit assez récent.

1894

VICTOR — Et tu les porteras ?
Mme FALAMPIN — Je te crois que je les porterai! Et larges de deux doigts.

https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_Vie_parisienne/i8mofusIJ6EC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22je+te+crois+que%22&pg=PA528&printsec=frontcover

2012

— Bien davantage, mon cher, c'est sans comparaison ! Ah, les gloires impériales s'en sont allées, Blay, et les infamies du présent s'en iront elles aussi, mais savoir quel avenir de merde nous attend ! Je crois que moi aussi je vais me commander un café anis… Dis donc, regarde un peu. Ce n'est pas le fils de Pep, ce garçon, là-bas, qui semble vouloir décrocher un illustré du kiosque ?
— Je te crois que c'est lui. Tu crois qu'il va faucher un illustré ? Il est un peu grand maintenant pour ce genre de lecture, non ?

https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Calligraphie_des_r%C3%AAves/i6OVDAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22je+te+crois+que%22&pg=PT138&printsec=frontcover

1955

— Je te crois que c'est embêtant!
https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_expression_du_haut_degr%C3%A9_en_fran%C3%A7ais/U2lfAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22je+te+crois+que%22&dq=%22je+te+crois+que%22&printsec=frontcover

1929

FLORENCE — Tu la reçois?
HENRI — Je te crois que je la reçois!
https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Sur_mon_beau_navire/RF4TAAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22je+te+crois+que%22&dq=%22je+te+crois+que%22&printsec=frontcover

Je maintiens donc que de nos jours, on n'entend pas cette tournure dans le langage des gens qui ont une certaine instruction.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135948/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-je-te-crois-que-les-sorcieres-existent).

Answer (score 0):

*Je te crois que...* n'est pas français.
*Je te crois **quand tu dis que** les sorcières existent.* est correct.
Le problème est le cumul de deux compléments sur le verbe croire :.
*je crois qui quoi :je crois qui ? (Toi). Et je crois quoi? (Que les sorcières existent).*
Les deux ensemble sont incorrects, d'où la nécessité de les séparer comme avec *tandis que* plus haut.
Une autre façon de les détacher serait : *Que les sorcières existent( , ou ?) je te crois*.

Comment: Je pense que de Maupassant avait en tête ce que l'on entend, et pas ce que l'on écrit. . « JE TE CROIS [quand tu dis] Qu'elle est belle ! »" Le français parlé n'est pas le français écrit...Il y a bel leurette que les écrivains le savent. Et la majuscule là laisse croire que la phrase vient "en sus" du "je te crois". –

Comment: @Earendelle Oui, mais ta phrase ne s'y trouve pas, et je ne changerai pas d'avis ici.

Comment: @Earendelle Ouais, alors je vois à ce sujet: **Elle  n'entre pas facilement dans les cadres syntaxiques**.  Justement, c'est pour ça qu'il faut chercher plutôt du côté de la grammaire du français parlé. https://www.actes-sud.fr/la-grande-grammaire-du-francais

Comment: Œuvre d’un large collectif de linguistes français et étrangers, la GGF voit le jour en 2021 sous la direction scientifique et éditoriale d’Anne Abeillé et Danièle Godard, en collaboration avec Annie Delaveau et Antoine Gautier.

Le projet a été initié en 2002 sous l’égide du CNRS, de la DGLFLF (Direction générale à la langue française et aux langues de France), et avec le soutien de nombreux laboratoires de recherche et universités françaises.

Comment: Le lecteurs futurs pourront lire les phrases et décider par eux-mêmes.

Comment: Merci pour tes égards.
Après réflexion, la question posée manque de contexte:  
Si je parle pour moi dans les deux cas, (ton hypothèse) la deuxième formulation est acceptable comme ' un peu que les sorcières existent !" ou le 'te' ne représente pas quelqu'un. 
Ma lecture , renforcée par le 'te' en gras, est qu'on discute de la validité de la source d'information : mon avis ou le tien. 
J'ai  une personne devant moi qui a dit 'les sorcières existent'.Je lui dis que je le crois. Dans cette acception, "je te crois que les sorcières existent"  nécessite une séparation pour être correct.

Comment: Une remarque: je ne comprends pas 'le tour' dans ton avant dernière remarque. Je pense que tu veux parler de 'la tournure (de phrase)'.

Comment: Oui c'est bien [ça](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4162), probablement moins usuel que _tournure_ mais plus court et j'aime le mot.